# What iis wrong with this imagesource in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I try to set an imagesource in code behind in WPF. For some reason it doesn't work - am I missing something?

```
ImageBrush imgBrushBackground = new ImageBrush();
imgBrushBackground.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Assets\img\bg_spaceFlare.jpg"));
```

The link to the file is correct (I checked it by dragging in an image from Solution Explorer).

The error message is this: System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'

Thanks!

Petter

Comment: In case you want to make the file an assembly resource, set its Build Action to Resource and load it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx), like `new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assets/img/bg_spaceFlare.jpg"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by passing [UriKind.Relative](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind(v=vs.110).aspx) to Uri's constructor:

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Assets\img\bg_spaceFlare.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
```